# How to make GridView Visible in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` on a form and it's not visible the browser even though `Visible` has been set to `True` in the Property Window. More so, I have the following code to enable data to be visible in the columns of the `GridView`, but nothing seems to work for me. I'd be glad if someone could help me out.

```
Sub showgrid()
     Try
         ds.Clear()
         ada = New SqlDataAdapter("Select SubjectCode'Subject Code',SubjectName'Subject Name',SubjectType'Subject Type',UserId'User Id',Password from ProgramDetails.Subjects", cn)
         ada.Fill(ds, "ProgramDetails.Subjects")
         cmd = New SqlCommand("Select SubjectCode'Subject Code',SubjectName'Subject Name',SubjectType'Subject Type',UserId'User Id',Password from ProgramDetails.Subjects", cn)
         ada.SelectCommand = cmd
         ada.Fill(ds)
         GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
     Catch ex As Exception
     End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you see it in the designer? What container does it belong to? Any related css?

Comment: Yes, I can see the GridView in the designer but can't see it in the browser.

Comment: The datasource must be empty.

Comment: DataSource is empty but it still cannot be displayed. I've however tried the following:  `GridView1.DataSource = ("Select SubjectCode'Subject Code',SubjectName'Subject Name',SubjectType'Subject Type',UserId'User Id',Password from ProgramDetails.Subjects")
            GridView1.DataBind()` which displays the GridView but without any data.

Comment: Why an empty try-catch block??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Try
        ds.Clear()
        ada = New SqlDataAdapter("Select SubjectCode'Subject Code',SubjectName'Subject Name',SubjectType'Subject Type',UserId'User Id',Password from ProgramDetails.Subjects", cn)
        ada.Fill(ds, "ProgramDetails.Subjects")
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Select SubjectCode'Subject Code',SubjectName'Subject Name',SubjectType'Subject Type',UserId'User Id',Password from ProgramDetails.Subjects", cn)
        ada.SelectCommand = cmd
        ada.Fill(ds)
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        GridView1.DataBind()'binds the datasource to the GridView
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are missing the `DataBind()` method for `GridView`.

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
GridView1.DataBind()   // Add this
```